# Prove the trigonometric Identity involving secant

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, trigonometry

The question I am currently working on is:
$\sec^2x-2\sec x\ \cos x+\cos^2x=\tan^2x-\sin^2x$.

Okay, judging by the expression here, I am going to need to work with the left side of the equation first, the $\sec^2x-2\sec x\ \cos x+\cos^2x$.  So I'm going to probably want to convert the secant ratios.  I know that $\sec^2-1=\tan^2x$ and that $\sec x=1/\cos x$.  The second option looks like it will be more useful in this case. Let me know how I am doing and if there are any errors or information that I should know about to finish this question, please :).

Comment: Both can be useful for the calculation.

Comment: A friendly reminder that visiting [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to type mathematics on this site will help make your posts much easier to read.  For the most part, even simply enclosing your formulae with \$ signs will make a big improvement on readability.

Comment: Okay, I will take a look at it.  Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: As for your question, note that $2\sec(x)\cos(x) = 2\cdot \frac{1}{\cos(x)}\cdot \cos(x) = 2 = 1+1$.  Try and use one of the 1's for simplifying one part, and the other 1 for simplifying the other part.

Comment: What I did so far was I got $(1/cosx)(1/cosx) for sec^2x$.  and $2(1/cosx)$ for 2secx --my appologies if I again didn't type properly.  I'm still figuring it all out.--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$secx=\frac{1}{cosx}$,then the left is $\frac{1}{cos^2 x}-2+cos^2 x=\frac{sin^2 x+cos^2 x}{cos^2 x}-2+cos^2 x=tan ^2 x-1+cos^2 x=right side$,hope it will be helpful.

Comment: I have been following your model and have managed to understand up to the point to get $1/cos^2x-2 + cos^2x$ on the left side.  However, how did you get the $sin^2x+cos^2x/cos^sx$, and how does this make it become the equivalent of the right side? Since $tan^2x=sec^2x-1$

Comment: Because $1=cos^2 x+sin^2 x$,you can replace 1 with them, you don't have to use $tan^2 x=sec^2 x-1$

Comment: Okay, well I see that now where the answer comes from, but I still do not understand quite how it is the equivalent to $tan^2x-sin^2x$ on the right side.

Comment: Oh,$-1+cos^2 x=-sin^2 x$ for the same reason $1=sin^2 x+cos^2 x$,right?

Comment: Yes. I see that.  I think I may be forgetting one of the identities here.

Comment: Nevermind, I worked the rest of it out and I got the right answer.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

By multiplying both terms by $\cos^2 x$ you are left to prove:
$$ 1-2\cos^2 x+\cos^4 x = \sin^2 x-\sin^2 x\cos^2 x \tag{1}$$
and that is straightforward to check by just replacing every occurrence of $\sin^2 x$ in the RHS with $1-\cos^2 x$.

Answer (score 1):

$$sec^2(x)-2sec(x)cos(x)+cos^2(x)=(sec(x)-cos(x))^2=$$$$\Big[\frac{1}{cos(x)}-cos(x)\Big]^2=\Big[\frac{1-cos^2(x)}{cos(x)}\Big]^2=$$$$\Big[\frac{sin^2(x)}{cos(x)}\Big]^2=\frac{sin^4(x)}{cos^2(x)}=\frac{sin^2(x)}{cos^2(x)}\cdot sin^2(x)=\frac{sin^2(x)}{cos^2(x)}[1-cos^2(x)]=$$$$tan^2(x)-sin^2(x)$$